# Redshift spectrum query never terminates when running on AWS Batch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psycopg2, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I've been making a pipeline for data migration, testing it all locally with Docker.
It worked like a charm, with no environment issues, and the result is as expected.

However, when I push and deploy the same Docker file to run the entire process on AWS Batch, one query never finishes, and eventually fails. That query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM redshift_spectrum_schema.table;
```

I tried to reduce the code to identify the problem. As a result, the following code works perfectly fine locally, but not on AWS Batch:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=os.environ["HOST"],
    port=int(os.environ["PORT"]),
    user=os.environ["USER"],
    password=os.environ["PASSWORD"],
    dbname=os.environ["DBNAME"]
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM redshift_spectrum_schema.table;"
cursor.execute(query)
```

I don't understand why there is such a difference between running locally and on AWS Batch.

[Redshift query dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pR8h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I successfully fixed it after few days of searching.

I had to adjust de MTU of the Batch instance to match the MTU of the Redshift cluster.

More details:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-drop-issues.html
- https://www.flydata.com/blog/how-to-make-ec2-mtu-settings-compatible-with-amazon-redshift/